# JDBC PreparedStatement in batch when columns to set vary from row to row

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, batch-processing

I am trying to batch updates using PreparedStatement where the data you get in varies in what you have available.

Simple example:

You have a table with column x and y. Your inputdata is a representation of rows where only the modified column is present. So for row 1 you have x='foo' and for row 2 you have y='bar'. In order to batch these with a PreparedStatement you need one SQL statement: "update table where x=?,y=? where etc".

The solution that I am working towards is setting the column where you dont have any value to the value that is already present, but I'm not sure if this is possible. In raw SQL you could write "update table where x=x and y='foo' where etc", however I haven't found any ways to achieve this by setting the "?" parameter to be a reference to the column, it seems it's not possible.

Is it possible to handle this case at all with PreparedStatements? I apologize if my explanation is poor.

Comment: Which DBMS product and JDBC driver are you using? Some drivers allow mixing different statements in a batch, some don't

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_nameI I'm using Oracle 18 something and corresponding ojdbc8 driver I believe.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For prepared statements, that would be non-standard extensions though.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the values you want to set are all non-null, you could use a statement like

```sql
update sometable set column1 = coalesce(?, column1), colum2 = coalesce(?, column2)
```

Then when the value should not be updated, use either `PreparedStatement.setNull` with an appropriate `java.sql.Types` value or a `PreparedStatement.setXXX` of the appropriate type with a `null` as value.

As discussed in the comments, an alternative if you do need to update to `null`, is to use a custom function with a sentinel value (either for updating to null or for using the current value). Something like:

```sql
update sometable set column1 = conditional_update(?, column1), colum2 = conditional_update(?, column2)
```

Where `conditional_update` would be something like (using Firebird 3 PSQL syntax):

```sql
create function conditional_update(new_value varchar(500), original_value varchar(500)) 
  returns varchar(500)
as
begin
  if (new_value = '$$NO_UPDATE$$') then
     return original_value;
  else
     return new_value;
end
```

Where using `$$NO_UPDATE$$` is a sentinel value for not updating. A potential downside of this solution is the typing of columns as a string type. You always need to use string types (I'm not sure if there are databases that would supports dynamic parameters and return types in this situation).

Comment: I found this myself yesterday and was buzzing, then I remembered that I cant guarantee that columns are non-null. But still this is a very nice solution if you dont have non-null values, thank you.

Comment: @oysandvik Having null values in the columns themselves is not a problem, what would be a problem is needing to be able to update to `null` from your input source.

Comment: @Matt Rotteveel Sorry, yes that is what I meant.

Comment: The only other solution I can think would involve a custom function that does the equivalent for a `coalesce`, with a sentinel value for updating to `NULL` (or a sentinel value for using the current value).

Comment: That's pretty interesting actually, I will try that out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase your problem and you please tell me if this is right:
You want to be able to have the update process

- sometimes you only update for a specific x
- sometimes you only update for a specific y
- sometimes you update for specific x and y combined

Correct? If 'yes' then the next issue is implementation possibilities.

You suggested trying to put the column itself into the parameter. Even if that's possible I'd still recommend against it. The code will get confusing.

I suggest you create a java method that builds and returns the query string (or at least the 'where' clause) based on your available parameters (x, y, etc)
Your code for invoking the JDBC Prepared statement will invoke that method to get a query String. 
You will still benefit from using prepared statements. The cost is that your database will be caching several different statements instead of one, but I imagine that is a minimal issue.

Comment: That is correct yes. If I understand your suggestion correctly then this is what I have done. My goal was however to reduce the amount of unique SQL statements, so basically having one PreparedStatement that could be used for all the 3 cases. I've done some more research since I posted this question and it seems that what I want to achieve is impossible. I thought about using NVL/Coalesce where I could handle this logic on the DB side, as I can just pass in null if there is a missing value, but this will break if someone actually wants to set a column to null.

Comment: Hi - just one more question, and comment - will the number of possible parameters be substantially larger than two? It's an interesting approach. I looked at some hacky/kludgy stuff (like using .setBoolean(1,true)) but that led me back to the question of whether such an approach would be more trouble than letting the  database deal with caching three statements rather than one. If you find a way to do this please let us know. Cheers!

Comment: The number of parameters can be quite large, in my specific case there is a quite gigantic database and a lot of different sources where data comes in. I haven't found a way to do it yet but Mark Rotteveel's answer using coalesce is very nice if you have non-null columns. If I find a good way I will for sure come back to this post. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can think of auxiliar "?" variable for each column which will manage if the column should be updated or not.

```
update table
set x = case when 0 = ? then x else ? end,
    y = case when 0 = ? then y else ? end
where etc;
```

Passing `0` for each `0 = ?` will not update the column whereas passing `1` will update it to the value you specified.